# How to use uniroot to solve a user-defined function (UDF) in a dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, user-defined-functions

I have a dataframe and want to use uniroot on each row to solve Implied Volatility based on Black-Scholes formula. What is the correct way to use uniroot.all to solve for each  row? It should produce a new column vector of results.

The code below has this error

> "Error in S/K : non-numeric argument to binary operator"

. I suspect the trouble comes when uniroot is trying to solve multiple rows instead of each row one-by-one.

I've tried to modify to a vectorized version of the bscall function but this doesn't seem to best way to do it.

```
df <- data.frame( strike = c(80,120,100,100), 
                  type = c("C", "C", "C","C"),
                  optionPrice = c(22,3,7,9),
                  futurePrice = c(100, 100,100,100),
                  time_to_expiry = c(0.1, 0.1,1,1.2))

bscall <-
  function (S,K,r,T,sig) {
    d1 <- (log(S/K)+(r+0.5*sig^2)*T) / (sig*sqrt(T)) 
    d2 <- d1 - sig*sqrt(T)
    price <- S*pnorm(d1) - K*exp(-r*T)*pnorm(d2)
    return(price)
  }


apply(df, 1,
      function(z) uniroot.all( function(x) bscall(z[4],z[1],r,z[5],x) - z[3], interval = c(0,1) ))
```

Answer (score 0):

The first row of `df` is `80, "C", 22, 100, 0.1`. It contains a character string. Therefore, when you do `apply(df, 1, ....)`, the rows are coerced to character vectors:

```
df <- data.frame( strike = c(80,120,100,100), 
                  type = c("C", "C", "C","C"),
                  optionPrice = c(22,3,7,9),
                  futurePrice = c(100, 100,100,100),
                  time_to_expiry = c(0.1, 0.1,1,1.2))

apply(df, 1, function(z) z)
#                [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4] 
# strike         " 80" "120" "100" "100"
# type           "C"   "C"   "C"   "C"  
# optionPrice    "22"  " 3"  " 7"  " 9" 
# futurePrice    "100" "100" "100" "100"
# time_to_expiry "0.1" "0.1" "1.0" "1.2"
```

Answer (score 0):

First: you should include the `library` statement you used for package `rootSolve`.
Where are variables `r` and `sig` defined?

There is no need for `uniroot.all` as you can see by inspecting function `bscall`. There is no need for iteration; `price` is calculated directly from the input.

Define df as follows taking into account the first answer.

```
df <- data.frame( strike = c(80,120,100,100), 
                  # type = c("C", "C", "C","C"),
                  optionPrice = c(22,3,7,9),
                  futurePrice = c(100, 100,100,100),
                  time_to_expiry = c(0.1, 0.1,1,1.2))
```

Column `type` has been commented out.

Define your function `bscall` as

```
bscall <-
  function (S,K,r,T,sig) {
  d1 <- (log(S/K)+(r+0.5*sig^2)*T) / (sig*sqrt(T)) 
  d2 <- d1 - sig*sqrt(T)
  price <- S*pnorm(d1) - K*exp(-r*T)*pnorm(d2)
  return(price)
}
```

Give `r` and `sig` a value

```
r <- .05
sig <- 1
```

Apply your function to rows of `df` (indices into `z` changed because of change to `df`)

```
apply(df, 1,
   function(z) bscall(z[3],z[1],r,z[4],sig) - z[2])
```

giving

```
[1]  2.258107  3.168623 32.840162 34.366636
```

as answer.

The rest is up to you.